# AngularJS execute controller method on page redirect

Tags: javascript, angularjs, controller, onload, ionic-framework

I build an app with Cordova/Phonegap, Ionic and AngularJS. I want to execute an inside method from a controller from outside. This inside method (secondMethod()) should be executed, when I redirect to another html (secondPage.html). My method runs a SQLite-query, to fetch some data and should display it on the new page. I tried it with an onload-function, but my console.log says, it can't find my function. How can I do this?

app.js

```
    ionicApp.controller("FirstController", function($scope) {

       $scope.firstMethod = function() {
          window.location.replace("secondPage.html");
       }

    }

    ionicApp.controller("SecondController", function($scope) {

       $scope.secondMethod = function() {
          // do some code
       }

       $scope.otherMethod = function() {
          // some other code
       }

    }
```

secondPage.html

```
    // html and head
    <body>
       <ion-content ng-controller="SecondController">
          <label id="text_label">Text</label>
          <button class="button" ng-click="otherFunction()">Button</button>
       </ion-content> 
       <script>
          window.onload=secondMethod();
       </script>
     </body>
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

thru using `$ionicView.enter` listener to execute your function? You can also try using the `resolve` functionality from [`ui-router`](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But how do I use $ionicView.enter? I figured out, that it should be used in a $scope.$on('$ionicView.enter', function(...)); function, but it does nothing. Can you also give an example with the resolve functionality?